# Kendo UI Mobile - data-* attribute for fixed headers in grouped listview?

Tags: html, listview, kendo-ui

I would like to have fixed headers in my group listview... I know how to do it using javascript, but was wondering if it is possible to achieve purely using kendo's data-* attributes?

something like the following:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-type="group" data-headers="fixed">
    <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: Answered below a month ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data attributes are hyphenated and lower case for the declarative initialization property of their camel-case counterparts in kendo mobile.

```
$("ul[data-role=listview]").kendoMobileListView({
        template: $("#listviewTemplate").html(),
        headerTemplate: $("#listviewHeaderTemplate").html(),
        type: "group",
        fixedHeaders: true
    });

<ul data-role="listview" data-template="listviewTemplate" data-header-template="listviewHeaderTemplate" data-type="group" data-fixed-headers="true">
    <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Framework version 2012.3.1315 apparently has a bug where fixed headers do not render properly and the first or last header in the listview is always shown.